# Scope issues when trying to clear Google map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I created a google map with this code:

```
function load() {
      var markersArray = [];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {

        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("getMapMarkers.php", function(data) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var brewID = markers[i].getAttribute("brewID");
          //construct url
          var breweryLink = "http://beerportfolio.com/breweryPage.php?id=" + brewID;

          //create directions link
          http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=
          var directionsLink = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=";
          directionsLink = directionsLink + markers[i].getAttribute("lat") +"," + markers[i].getAttribute("lng")

          var html = "<b><a href=\"" + breweryLink + "\">"+name+"</a> </b> <br/>" ;
          html = html + "<br> <br>";
          html = html + "<a  href=\"" + directionsLink + " \">(Click for Directions)</a>";
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          markersArray.push(marker);



          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
          bounds.extend(point);

        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });


    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function getMapVisit()
    {
        alert("clearing overlays...");
        clearOverlays();

        return false;
    }

function clearOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}



function setAllMap(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

    function doNothing() {}
```

When I try an delete the markers to re-load different ones, I cannot delete them off the map.

On button press I call `getMapVisit()` which then calls `clearOverlays()`, but `clearOverlays()` doesn't clear the map. In Chrome, when I inspect the element I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: markersArray is not defined
```

The error is called on line 86 which is:

```
if (markersArray) {
```

I do not know why its not defined when its clearly initialized array at the top of `load()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `var markersArray = [];` above the `load` function so it will be `globally` defined and will be accessible in all the functions .

Comment: awesome that worked! Now if I want to reload in a different set of markers how would I do that with this code?

Comment: I wasnt sure if that would load the whole map again or just the markers. I will give it a try

Comment: It worked, thanks! It kind of reloads the whole map but it works. It would be nice to load the markers so they drop in, instead of reloading the whole thing. But this gets things done!